# How to find the missing dependency in failed compilation?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker-errors, undefined-reference

Sometimes when compiling the errors output the name of a header file that is missing, and the package it comes from can be tracked down using the Linux package manager.

But how to find the missing dependency when the error is of the sort below, where it doesn't give you the name of the missing header file?

```
make[2]: *** [examples/undocumented/libshogun/base_map_parameters] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:916: recipe for target 'examples/undocumented/libshogun/CMakeFiles/base_map_parameters.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/undocumented/libshogun/CMakeFiles/base_map_parameters.dir/all] Error 2
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `SZ_BufftoBuffDecompress'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `SZ_encoder_enabled'
../../../src/shogun/libshogun.so.17.1: undefined reference to `SZ_BufftoBuffCompress'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
examples/undocumented/libshogun/CMakeFiles/base_migration_dropping_and_new.dir/build.make:129: recipe for target 'examples/undocumented/libshogun/base_migration_dropping_and_new' failed
```

Comment: You have a linker error; it is not a header file but an implementation file that you are missing (be that a source file or a pre-compiled library). If you were missing a header, presumably you would have an error before the linking stage (e.g., a `no such function exists` error).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header file example you present is a compile time error.  The compiler knows about the files and can present you with what is missing.  The error you are presenting above is a link time error.

The one you present is a common one and it is that a symbol is not defined.  Usually this happens because a library was excluded from the linker line.  Another common source of this error is that the library you are linking to is older than the one expected for the program.

Usually I find myself trolling Google for articles like [this one](https://github.com/PacificBiosciences/blasr/issues/4) when presented with such errors.  The packaging manager does not track function level details when accounting for files or libraries.  I always thought it would be nice enhancement to inspect libraries with the nm command and put that meta data into packaging systems.

Answer (score 3):

(This is not a generic answer, but) In this case, [googling SZ_BufftoBuffDecompress](https://www.google.de/search?q=SZ_BufftoBuffDecompress) gave, among others, the link to https://github.com/PacificBiosciences/blasr/issues/4, where it is [suggested](https://github.com/ylipacbio)

> It seems that the hdf5 library is not correctly installed. The hdf5 lib that you used requires szip library. So you may need to install szip lib first and then re-make your hdf5 package (linking it with the szip lib, -lsz).

So it seems as though the **missing dependency is szip**.

As for **general searching**, @Thomas Padron-McCarthy's comment sensibly advises to

> perhaps add the program name

and

> on Ubuntu I might also add `apt-get` and `install`, to directly find instructions on how to install the missing parts!

If you **only need the software**, and do not feel the need to compile it yourself, have a look at the github post. [Another poster](https://github.com/sjackman)

> suggest[s] using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and Linuxbrew to install [science](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science) software on Mac and Linux, repsectively[sic].

Comment: Yes, Google is what I always use. Copy the error message into the Google search field, perhaps add the program name, and you are likely to find a discussion about the error and how to solve it. When I'm on Ubuntu I might also add "apt-get" and "install", to directly find instructions on how to install the missing parts!